# Is there a way to generate a number of Woocommerce coupons based on a certain amount?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I'm fixing a plugin-loaded Woocommerce site and now I have a requirement to implement an automatic coupon generator based on the purchase amount: for example, I would like to establish a rule for every $100 purchase, if the customer buys $450, 4 discount coupons of $40 will be generated. All of this codes should be sent to the customer.

I've reviewed the WooCommerce documentation where I can create the coupons: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/ and already implemented it and sending in the order review mail (after payment has been confirmed):

```
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

    if ( ! $sent_to_admin && $order->get_user_id() && 'processing' == $order->get_status()) {

        $lista_cupones  = array();
        $amount = '40';

        for ($i=1; $i<=$order->get_total()/100; $i++) {

            $longitud = 12;
            $key = '';
            $pattern = '1234567890ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWYZ';
            $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
            for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
            $coupon_code = $key;

            $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; 
            $coupon = array(
                'post_title' => $coupon_code,
                'post_content' => ''.$to,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
            );

            $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'minimum_amount', '100' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_sale_items', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_sale', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', strtotime("+3 days") );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );

            array_push($lista_cupones, $coupon_code);

        }
        echo '<h2>';

        printf( __( 'Obt&eacute;n 40 soles de descuento')
        );
        echo '</h2>';

        printf(
            __( 'Gracias por su compra. Use el código de descuento <strong>%2$s</strong> para recibir %1$s soles de descuento en su siguiente compra.'),
            $amount,
            $coupon_code
        );
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table','add_order_email_instructions',10);
```

Now this half works: it validates if order total is less than $100 and doesn't generate a coupon but if it's higher it only gives me one coupon even if order total is 200, 300 400, etc. (it doesn't even generate more than one coupon, seems like it only goes through the loop once and stops).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved, this is the code:

```
function create_coupon () {
    $amount = '40';
    $longitud = 12;
    $key = '';
    $pattern = '1234567890ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWYZ';
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    $coupon_code = $key;

    $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; 
    $coupon = array(
        'post_title' => $coupon_code,
        'post_content' => ''.$to,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
    );

    $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'minimum_amount', '100' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_sale_items', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_sale', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', strtotime("+3 days") );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'customer_email', $order->get_billing_email());

    return $coupon_code;
}

function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

        if ( ! $sent_to_admin && $order->get_user_id() && 'processing' == $order->get_status()) {

            $lista_cupones  = [];
            $numero_cupones = $order->get_total()/100;
            for ($i=1; $i<=$numero_cupones; $i++) { 
                array_push($lista_cupones, create_coupon());
            }
            echo '<h2>';

            printf( __( 'Obt&eacute;n 40 soles de descuento')
            );
            echo '</h2>';

            printf(
                __( 'Gracias por su compra. Use el código de descuento <strong>%2$s</strong> para recibir %1$s soles de descuento en su siguiente compra.'),
                $amount,
                $lista_cupones 
            );
            echo '<br></p>';
        }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table','add_order_email_instructions',10);
```

This is unfinished, now I have to show it in the adequate array format within the mail